# how to pass vars from different files to express router

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have issues trying to render object's data threw the express router.

I have a file `dummy.js` and inside of it I have `var user = "rally"`.

How can I pass this var to the `routes.js` file and use it inside `res.render`.
so if I want to render `welcome.html` with the user var value, how should I pass it to the function:

```
router.get('/welcome', secure-pages, function(req, res, next){
    res.render('welcome', {title:'Welcome', user:--VALUE TO GO HERE--});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could include the value with the module.exports variable. In your dummy.js file, add anything you want to give to another file in the module.exports variable like so:

```
var user = "rally";

module.exports = {
  user:user
};
```

Then in your original file include the dummy.js with require() like this:

```
var dummy = require('./dummy.js');
console.log(dummy.user); // rally
```

or as in your question you could implement it like this:

```
var dummy = require('./dummy.js');

router.get('/welcome', secure-pages, function(req, res, next){
        res.render('welcome', {title:'Welcome', user:dummy.user});
    });
```